# Does this query have to be nested?

Tags: mysql, database, sql

I have the following query:

```
select group_concat(customer_name) customer_names,
       count(customer_name) number_of_customers,
       line_1,
       line_2,
       city,
       state_name,
       zip
  from (select c.name customer_name,
               ad.*,
               s.name state_name
          from address ad
          join account_address aa on aa.address_id = ad.id
          join account a on aa.account_id = a.id
          join customer c on a.customer_id = c.id
          join state s on ad.state_id = s.id
 group by c.name) a
 group by state_name, city, line_1, line_2
 order by state_name, city, line_1, line_2
```

Did I have to nest it the way I did to get the two layers of grouping? I would prefer not to have any subqueries if I don't have to.

Edit: this is the query I ended up using:

```
select group_concat(distinct c.name) customer_names,
       count(distinct c.name) number_of_customers,
       line_1,
       line_2,
       city,
       s.name,
       zip
  from address ad
  join account_address aa on aa.address_id = ad.id
  join account a on aa.account_id = a.id
  join customer c on a.customer_id = c.id
  join state s on ad.state_id = s.id
group by s.name, city, zip, line_1, line_2
order by s.name, city, zip, line_1, line_2
```

Comment: Yeah, MySQL. I have to add more characters to this comment in order for it to be "valid" because Stack Overflow is stupid. Hope you're happy, Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is there a reason you are anti-subquery?

Comment: @JNK: they are somewhat inefficient in `MySQL` (they are buffered before further processing). There is a reason to avoid them. And these are not the subqueries, these are inline views.

Comment: @Quassnoi - Can you tell I work mainly in SQL Server? :) Thanks!

Comment: @JNK: I just don't want the query to be more complicated than it has to be. Performance is not foremost on my mind right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The innermost query selects one (random) address from all those defined for customers with same names. (The `state`, by the way, does not even have to belong the the address)

The query seems to be counting the customers by state, city and street address. What if the customer has more than one address? Should they be counted once or twice (and if once, on which address)?

In other words, what should the query return for addresses like this:

```
Customer1  NY  NYC   Broadway
Customer1  CA  LA    Sunset Boulevard
Customer2  CA  LA    Sunset Boulevard
```

Do you have three or two customers in total? If two, do they both live in `LA`?

**Update:**

If you want duplicates on each address, then you don't need the innermost `GROUP BY` at all:

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT (DISTINCT customer_name) customer_names,
        COUNT(DISTINCT customer_name) number_of_customers,
        line_1,
        line_2,
        city,
        state_name,
        zip
FROM    address ad
JOIN    state s
ON      s.id = ad.state_id
JOIN    account_address aa
ON      aa.address_id = ad.id
JOIN    account a
ON      a.id = aa.account_id
JOIN    customer c
ON      c.id = a.customer_id
GROUP BY
        ad.state_id, ad.city, ad.line_1, ad.line_2
```

Create an index on `address (state_id, city, line_1, line_2)` for this to work faster.

Note that if it's possible to have different zip codes for same addresses, it's not defined which of them will be returned.

Comment: My end goal is to show groups of customers who share addresses.

Comment: The result I would want here is one row showing ({Customer1, Customer2}, Sunset Boulevard) and another row showing ({Customer1}, Broadway).

Comment: @Jason: then you don't need the innermost `GROUP BY` at all.

Comment: This worked (after I changed state_name to s.name, etc.). Interestingly, your query is slower than Jason McCreary's, apparently due to the order of the JOINs. I selected yours as the correct answer, though, because you made sure you were addressing the end goal. I wish I could select both answers as correct.

Comment: @Jason, no worries. **Quassnoi** provided a much more detailed answer. Although you should note that I added `zip` to your `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` statements for completeness. MySQL 5+ allows selecting an *ungrouped* field. However, other RDBMS don't.

Comment: @Jason: `JOIN` order is not important, it's `GROUP BY` columns that matter. Jason McCreary has an extra `zip` in the column list and you most probably have a composite index on these columns.

Comment: Also, there's one more problem: If one person has multiple accounts, his name shows up multiple times in the GROUP_CONCAT(). This is what the innermost JOIN was supposed to fix, but it "fixed" it wrong. Any advice there?

Comment: @Jason: If a customer has two accounts with same addresses, do you still want to count them as two customers (as you did for customers that have multiple different addresses)?

Comment: No, just one customer. My end goal here is to answer the question "Who lives at each address in the system?"

Comment: @JasonSwett: see post update. Note that if two different customers have the same names and live at the same address, they will be counted as one customer. If it's not acceptable, you will have to revert to a nested query.

Comment: Outstanding. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your other two columns are using aggregate functions, I don't think you need the nested query. But without testing it against your data, it's tough to be sure.

Try this and see:

```
select group_concat(customer_name) customer_names,
       count(customer_name) number_of_customers,
       line_1,
       line_2,
       city,
       state_name,
       zip
          from address ad
          join account_address aa on aa.address_id = ad.id
          join account a on aa.account_id = a.id
          join customer c on a.customer_id = c.id
          join state s on ad.state_id = s.id
 group by state_name, city, zip, line_1, line_2
 order by state_name, city, zip, line_1, line_2
```

You should really prefix your columns with tables in these types of queries, i.e. `c.customer_name`

Comment: Your query worked (after I changed state_name to s.name, etc.) but it gave a slightly different number of results (7746 vs. my 7667). I don't know which result is right (probably yours).

Comment: @Jason, interesting. Tough to say without seeing the data. But based strictly by your table structure, I will humbly say that the above is probably the better query.